# QMouseEvent to win32 MOUSEINPUT

Tags: winapi, qt, mouseevent

I need to convert a `QMouseEvent` to [`MOUSEINPUT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646273%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). `MOUSEINPUT` has so many flags like `MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN`, `MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP` but `QMouseEvent` has very limited number of actions. do there is any existing solution ? If I need to wrte it by myself how can I cover the gaps ?

Comment: could you explain a bit why you need to convert this? mixing Win32 API calls with Qt calls is generally a recipe for strange bugs.

Comment: I actually need to carry forward the Mouse and Keyboard events from 1 machine to another over the socket.

Answer (score 1):

QT covers all cases of mouse using, but it splitted them to different variables instead of  `MOUSEINPUT`.
for example,
`MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN` would be 
`QMouseEvent` with `type = QEvent::MouseButtonPress , button = Qt::LeftButton.`
and so on.
The only win events not covered by qt are strange events `MOUSEEVENTF_XDOWN` and `MOUSEEVENTF_XUP`